# New PC, boots fine, but no USB devices work AsRock H61m-itx

Tags: usb, motherboard

I just bought a second hand PC

Mobo : ASRock H61m-itx UEFI P1.70
Intel CPU G870

It boots fine, but no USB devices actually work. They receive power ( the mouse becomes illuminated etc ). The keyboard - none of the buttons work (e.g. pressing F1 during boot does nothing ).

I'm trying to install windows from USB, but it doesn't prompt for install from boot menu, and I cannot check the boot device priority because I cannot get into the bios menu.

I have a Logitech G11 keyboard - USB, unfortunately I don't have a Ps2 keyboard to check if that works..

I have reset the bios ( removed CMOS battery for 20 minutes ), but that didn't help.

Is there anything I can do to test/fix it? I probably already know the answer to this question: 'Nothing you can do, motherboard is dead' or 'Yep, shouldnt be buying second hard stuff on ebay' etc. But I thought I would give this a go..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried booting from a CD of some sort to see whether you can boot off of that and have the keyboard work? Also, does it have a bios reset jumper on it? To me, it sounds like legacy usb isn't enabled, which could prevent keyboard from working.

Comment: Yep, I reset the BIOS. I don't have a SATA CD drive. No luck

Comment: Any chance you have a USB to PS/2 adapter? Without having a PS/2 keyboard, I'm not really sure if there's anything else you can do to confirm for sure.

Comment: If usb does not work on boot then there is something wrong with that used mobo.

Comment: Assuming you have multiple USB ports make sure you are plugged into a USB 2.0 port and not a 3.0 port.  I have seen that make a difference on rare occasion.